# Use setDirectory() method in JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

How to enter the path of the directory in which you want to create a Git repository using JGit API method `setDirectory()`?

I am using setDirectory() to create a local Repository using the below syntax:

```
Git git = Git.init().setDirectory().call();
```

Comment: Also if there is any other way to create a Repository using JGit API?

Comment: The article [Initializing Git Repositories with JGit](http://www.codeaffine.com/2015/05/06/jgit-initialize-repository/) explains JGit's `InitCommand` and related APIs in detail.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your directory/path to [setDirectory()](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.5.0.201609210915-r/apidocs/index.html) method like this with a File object pointing to your desired directory:

```
Git git = Git.init().setDirectory( directory ).call();
```